# Word for something that spreads

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word (possibly an adjective) for something that spreads (perhaps rapidly)? This would refer to a virus but without the obvious bad connotation.

Comment: Most things that spread are bad: fire, disease, floodwaters... What context do you need this word for? The more information you can provide, the better we can answer. (Also, without more context, this is in danger of being closed as "not a real question", because some of the Powers-That-Be are severely allergic to single-word-requests.)

Comment: Why do you not want it to have bad connotations? Have you checked the thesaurus for [spread](http://thesaurus.com/browse/spread)? Any reason any of the nouns there are not to you liking?

Comment: Please make it more clear. In what context will you use it?

Comment: From the headline, I thought you were asking for one of [these](http://amzn.com/B00004OCJ9). I think this question falls under general reference...

Comment: It's sort of for a social project, I think I'm going to go with "Expand" (although words in that direction would be welcome)

Comment: What refers to a virus?  Are you talking about a virus or a weed or an idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term [Viral](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/viral) has been co-opted and is no longer considered only a bad connotation.  The phrase going viral is generally considered a good thing(unless you are the one being embarrassed in the video or ad)

> quickly and widely spread or popularized especially by
>   person-to-person electronic communication

Answer (score 6):

*Infectious* is my one-word answer.

Comment: Surely this has the same bad connotations as *virus*? The question asks for something without obvious bad connotations.

Comment: Not necessarily. We often speak of someone's enthusiasm or happiness being contagious or infectious.

Comment: @Matt: both 'viral' and 'infectious' are weaker and not terribly negative (if at all) in contexts other than disease. 'infectious humor' and alcas's examples.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that it's not absolutely essential to emphasise the "spatial" connotations of *spread*, though they're often present by implication in my offerings anyway.

I'm also guessing that the thing itself at least in part produces it's own momentum causing it to spread - we're talking more about something like a virus that *spreads itself*, rather than something like plaster being spread on a wall by a tradesman.

The process of spreading is **proliferation**. The adjective [prolific](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prolific) is normally used of something that *has already spread*, but if OP doesn't mind sounding a bit "erudite", he can use [proliferatory](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proliferatory&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) to describe something which has the *potential to spread*, even if it hasn't actually done so yet.

Answer (score 1):

*[Propagate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/propagate)*, "To cause to ... multiply by generation" or "To cause to spread to extend" (sic) or "To spread from person to person..." may serve.  Also see its [synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=propagate&send=Look+it+up) that include *disperse, disseminate, spread*.

Adjective *[epidemic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epidemic)* means "Like or having to do with an epidemic; widespread", *eg* "Epidemic hysteria occurred upon the incumbent’s reelection."

***Comment:*** *Propagate* and its synonyms mentioned above are verbs.  If you want other word forms, clarify the question and indicate if you are looking for words to be used as *spreading, growing, burgeoning* would be used, or as *ductile, malleable, miscible* would be used, *etc*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest contagious. It has a very similar meaning without a negative connotation.

Answer (score -2):

[*Pervasive*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pervade).

> *pervade*, verb [ with obj. ]
>   (esp. of a smell) spread through and be perceived in every part of: a smell of stale cabbage pervaded the air.

Comment: Always cite your sources.

Comment: Something that is pervasive _has already_ spread. A pervasive virus is not the same as a virus that spreads quickly.